# Find a given distribution is involutive and a flat chart for the distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, foliations

Hello I am studying distributions and foliations by myself, I got stuck on an exercise. Let $\mathcal{D}\subset T\mathbb{R}^{3}$ generated by the vector fields $X=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+x(y+1)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$ Prove that $\mathcal{D}$ is involutive, and determine a local flat chart centered in the origin for the foliation induced by $\mathcal{D}.$
The distribution is clearly involutive because $[X,Y]=-Y$ and the vector fields $X$ and $Y$ are global frame for the distribution. As for the flat chart I had some difficulties I tried to use the following approach. What I want are new coordinates for which $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}}=\tilde{X}$ and $Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{y}}$ where $\tilde{X}$ is a $C^{\infty}$ linear combination of $X$ and $Y$, such that $[\tilde{X},Y]=0$.
I chose
$$\tilde{X}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$$

Then I needed a third vector field which in the origin is linearly independent from $\tilde{X}$ and $Y$, I chose $Z=\frac{\partial}{\partial z},$ then I used the change of coordinates formula to write a sistem of PDE hoping to be able to solve it.
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{x}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar{x}}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial \bar{x}}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$$
So I have obtained the following system
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{x}}=0,\,\frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar{x}}=1, \, \frac{\partial z}{\partial \bar{x}}=x \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{y}}=1,\,
\frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar{y}}=0,\,
\frac{\partial z}{\partial \bar{y}}=y \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{z}}=0,\,\frac{\partial y}{\partial\bar{z}}=0,\,
\frac{\partial z}{\partial \bar{z}}=1$$
Since I have already tried to solve it without success could someone at least guarantee me that this is the right path on which to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have $Y= \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ for some coordinate system $\lbrace u, v, w\rbrace$, you need to find (independent) functions such that $Y(u) =1, Y(v) = 0= Y(w) $.

You can take $u= x, v= y$, and $w$ will be some other function with $Y(w) =0$. By guessing, you can see that $w= xy-z$ is such function.

In this same system of coordinates, your $\tilde{X}$ is equal to $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not thought of that! The component of the charts are real valued functions on which the vector field can act.